# Compute the similarity between two lists of objects

Tags: algorithm, similarity, information-retrieval, cosine-similarity

I'd like to compute the similarity between two lists of various lengths. In particular, the similarity has to take into account different conditions:

-Given 2 list A and B, if A=B then similarity(A,B)=1

-In general, if B contains A, then similarity (A,B)->1. However, the measure of similarity should also take into consideration the number of elements of the two list. (E.g. if A contains 1000 objects and B just one, which is also contained in A, then similarity(A,B)->0).

-Similarity(A,B) defines also a threshold T. Values of similarity grater than T indicate that the two lists are similar.

Cosine similarity is probably related to this problem, but I have no idea how to work with subset and treshold.

I have found also different approaches, but threshold pararameter is snot specified:

-[A Similarity Measure for Indefinite Rankings](http://www.williamwebber.com/research/papers/wmz10_tois.pdf)

-[Kendall rank correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient)

Comment: The desired similarity function is not clear at all. There are millions of functions that would fit your few requirements, but would give very different results for the same input. You'll have to be much more precise.

Comment: Thank you for your very interesting answer. As you can see other users managed to identify some measures related to the problem. Maybe by reading the articles, you'll be able to better understand the requirements.

Comment: Requirements should be listed inside the question itself, not in linked articles.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for some kind of set similarity.

The two most prominent measures for that are [Jaccard Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) and [Sørensen–Dice coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8rensen%E2%80%93Dice_coefficient)

Answer (score 1):

In your case, Using **[Jaccard similarity coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index)** might help.